# PATCH & PUT routes in Rails upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, routes, put

Okay,

I'm in the middle of upgrading our Rails 3 application from Rails 3.2 onto Rails 4.2. After reading through the upgrade notes and the changes, we are running into a weird issue with some `PUT` and `PATCH` routes.

In our Rails 3 application, we have the following route defined:

```
resources :entities, except: [:show] do
  member do
    put :change_monitoring_status
  end
 end
```

When running `rake routes`, the `change_monitoring_status` route shows up as a proper `PUT` route. The form being generated for this using the Rails helpers generates the correct request in Rails 3.

In Rails 4 however, this form is now producing a `PATCH` route instead. Which is totally okay as this is now the standard behaviour in Rails. However, when we use the form on Rails 4 Production, this results in a `404 - Not Found`.

We tried to write an RSpec test for this to mimic the same behaviour and close the bug ticket. So for our Rails 4 upgrade, we wrote the following test:

```
describe '#change_monitoring_status' do

  before(:each) do
    sign_in user
  end

  it 'fails when put is used' do
    expect {
      put :change_monitoring_status, id: entity.id, _method: "PUT", form_object: {  }
    }.to raise_error
  end

  it 'works when patch is used' do
    expect {
      patch :change_monitoring_status, id: supplier.id, _method: "PATCH", form_object: {  }
    }.to_not raise_error
  end
end
```

We also changed the route to be `PATCH` instead of `PUT` now.

---

This is the behaviour we are seeing:

- The `PUT` test fails on Rails 4, because no 404 is raised
- The `PATCH` test succeeds
- The `PUT` request works on production
- The `PATCH` request fails on production

The way we understand this, is not in line with the documentation. The form is generating a proper `PATCH` request, yet we cannot get the correct behaviour going in the RSpec tests.

What we expect:

- `PUT` to raise a 404
- `PATCH` to succeed

Gems used:
* Rails 4.2
* RSpec 3.4
* RSpec-rails 3.4
* simple_form 3.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Controllers spec fake the whole request cycle. The request never really hits the routing layer - RSpec just looks for a route in the routes file which matches the controller and the action.

While this is good for speed since you skip the whole Rack layer it can sometimes mask routing errors.

Also there is a slight difference in your specs; the first uses `id: entity.id` while the latter uses `id: supplier.id`.

In this case I would use a [routing spec](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-4/docs/routing-specs) or a request spec instead since this should cause an error in the routing layer - before the controller is even matched.

```
describe "change_monitoring_status", type: :routing do

  it 'fails when put is used' do
    expect(puts: "/entity/37/change_monitoring_status").not_to be_routable
  end

  it 'works when patch is used' do
    expect(patch: "/entity/37/change_monitoring_status").to 
      route_to(
         controller: "entities", 
         action: "change_monitoring_status", 
         id: 37
      )
  end
end
```

Comment: yeah I was just browsing through the entire rails documentation about routes and it's explicitly written there for the `get` method that they are not checked at all. This is extremely confusing.....

Comment: It makes a bit more sense if you look at [ActionController::TestCase](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb), its not really creating a http request and hitting your application just simulating one and using it to instantiate the controller. This lets you poke inside the controller in a way which would not be possible otherwise. If you really want to hit the Rails stack via HTTP you would use a [request spec](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec).